# SQL query: joining 3 tables with multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm stuck trying to combine multiple tables into a json object I can use.  Hopefully, I can explain what I'm trying to do.

I have 3 tables:

**transactions table**

id, client, address, city, state, zip

**agents table**

id, first_name, last_name

**agent_transaction**

id, agent_id, transaction_id

---

Here's how they're all tied together:

transactions.id = agent_transaction.transaction_id

agent_transaction.agent_id = agents.id

---

A single transaction can have multiple agents (inserted into agent_transaction).  I'm looking to get the following out of a SQL query:

Get a list of each transactions...along with all of the agents assigned to the transaction...and gather the agent information (first_name, last_name, etc).

So, it would look something like this:

alltransactions:[ {

```
id: 20
client: Joe Smith
address:  123 Fake Dr
city: Phoenix
state: AZ
zip: 85248
agents:{
    agent_id: 39
    first_name: John
    last_name: Doe
},{
    agent_id: 40
    first_name: Kelly
    last_name: Parker
},{
    agent_id: 41
    first_name: Carl
    last_name: Williams
}
```

},{

```
id: 21
client: Mary Swamson
address:  240 Someplace Dr
city: Seattle
state: WA
zip: 98233
agents:{
    agent_id: 12
    first_name: Billy
    last_name: Banks
},{
    agent_id: 98
    first_name: Sharon
    last_name: Gandt
}
```

}
]

I've tried using a few inner joins, but I get duplicate transaction rows for every agent returned.  I'm playing around with the STRING_AGG function right now, hoping that might return what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: If you want that literal JSON output from a query, then you will have to use the JSON libraries provided by MySQL (Postgres?).  The duplication you are seeing from the join is expected.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks Tim.  The JSON output isn't my issue, I can take care of that.  Even when I try to run simple SQL queries from within psql, I am getting duplicate transactions (one for each agent returned).  Is there a way to get unique transactions, and have agent info as some sort of an array within each result?  I really just need to know the transaction details and all of the agents assigned to it.

Comment: I'm thinking the STRING_AGG function in postgresql might do what I want.

Comment: You might want to remove the MySQL if you are using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out, using STRING_AGG:

```
SELECT t.id,t.address, STRING_AGG(a.first_name, ';') AS agents FROM trans AS t
    INNER JOIN agent_trans AS at ON (t.id = at.transaction_id)
    INNER JOIN agents AS a ON (a.id = at.user_id)
    GROUP BY t.id,t.address
    ORDER BY t.id;
```

I obviously need to include all of my other fields, but this seems to be what I'm looking for.